# Can a non independent character deploy in a dedicated transport?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Can a non independent character (not attached and not attachable to the unit) deploy in a dedicated transport of any unit?

I'm thinking of putting Death Cie. Tycho with 9 Death Cie. inside the unit's drop pod. I'm not sure if that's allowed.

And according to the errata, Tycho is a single unit in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Tycho has two different profiles, Captain Tycho and Death Company Tycho.

Since Death Company Tycho is not an independent character (codex p. 41, FAQ p. 4), it is disallowed by the Dedicated Transport rules (p. 78):

```
The only limitation of a Dedicated Transport is that when it is
deployed, it can only carry the unit it was selected with (plus
any Independent Characters that have joined it).
```

Answer (score 0):

An independant character can attach itself to a unit, once dont so they function as a single unit for all purposes. This means that as long as the unit can fit into a transport (not to many modles after you add the IC) then the "unit" can start in the transport.

I am unfamilar with the Tycho characters rules but if he can join a unit then there is no reason him and the unit cannot be put ina drop pod.

From the sounds of you post i would say tycho cannot be placed in the unit as he is not an IC therfore cannot go in the drop pod.